Terraform and Azure policy interaction issue
We have a deployment of a VNET with bicep which works fine. Moving to Terraform and there are issues with Azure policy.
We have a policy which denies the creation of subnets with no NSGs. This is fine with Bicep as it seems to create the NSG link to the subnet as an atomic operation. Terraform doesn't do this - it creates the subnet without an NSG attached and then runs a separate Terraform resource which connects them and so the subnet creation fails because of the policy. Same issue for Route tables.
Any general comment on this? There is no way to defer policy eval until after Terraform has finished and no inline way to force Terraform to do such things as an atomic operation ...


There is no way to defer policy eval until after Terraform has finished and no inline way to force Terraform to do such things as an atomic operation

You can create one or more subnets associated to Network Security Groups (NSG) using the subnet block of the azurerm_virtual_network resource:

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  
  # ....

  subnet {
    name           = "subnet1"
    address_prefix = "10.0.1.0/24"
    security_group = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
  }

  subnet {
    name           = "subnet2"
    address_prefix = "10.0.2.0/24"
    security_group = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
  }
}


I'm afraid we can't inline the subnets as we have to have the option of adding new separate subnet resources later.

@PLK AFAIK there's no other workaround for this issue.

Another example of the azurerm provider not being adequate and it appears that there is a reason it is done this way and HC don't intend to change this as it breaks other things. So, I reverted to the azapi provider and which works fine for creating subnets in this scenario as it does atomic creation, along with the NSG/RT link.

If you are open to using for_each with your modules , I would recommend using it, it will make it easier to add subnets in the future .
eg:
variables:
variable "virtual_networks" {
  type = map(object({
    name                    = string
    location                = string
    address_space           = list(string)
    resource_group_name     = string
    virtual_network_tags = map(string)
  }))
}

variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    name                                          = string
    resource_group_name                           = string
    virtual_network_name                          = string
    address_prefixes                              = list(string)
  }))
}

variable "network_security_groups" {
  type = map(object({
    name                        = string
    resource_group_name         = string
    location                    = string
    network_security_group_tags = map(string)
  }))
}

variable "subnet_network_security_group_associations" {
  type = map(object({
    subnet_variable_name                 = string
    network_security_group_variable_name = string
  }))
}

tfvars:
virtual_networks = {
  vnet1 = {
    name                    = "vnet1"         
    location                = "canadacentral" 
    address_space           = ["10.0.0.0/16"] 
    resource_group_name     = "test-rg"       
    virtual_network_tags = {
      applicationName = "Virtual Network"
      approver        = "IT Infrastructure"
    }
  }
}

subnets = {
  subnet1 = {
    name                                          = "subnet1" 
    resource_group_name                           = "test-rg"                       
    virtual_network_name                          = "vnet1"                         
    address_prefixes                              = ["10.0.0.0/26"]                 
  },
  subnet2 = {
    name                                          = "subnet2" 
    resource_group_name                           = "test-rg"             
    virtual_network_name                          = "vnet1"               
    address_prefixes                              = ["10.0.1.0/26"]       
  }
}

network_security_groups = {
  network_security_group1 = {
    name                = "nsg1"          
    resource_group_name = "test-rg"       
    location            = "canadacentral"  
    network_security_group_tags = {
      applicationName = "Network Security Group"
      approver        = "IT Infrastructure"
    }
  },
network_security_group2 = {
        name                = "nsg2"          
        resource_group_name = "test-rg"       
        location            = "canadacentral"  
        network_security_group_tags = {
          applicationName = "Network Security Group"
          approver        = "IT Infrastructure"
        }
      }
}

subnet_network_security_group_associations = {
  nsg_association1 = {
    subnet_variable_name                 = "subnet1"                 
    network_security_group_variable_name = "network_security_group1" 
  }                                                                  ,
   nsg_association2 = {
       subnet_variable_name = "subnet2"                  
       network_security_group_variable_name = "network_security_group1" 
   }
}

Module
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtual_network" {
  for_each                = var.virtual_networks
  name                    = each.value["name"]
  location                = each.value["location"]
  resource_group_name     = each.value["resource_group_name"]
  address_space           = each.value["address_space"]
  tags = each.value["virtual_network_tags"]
} 

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each                                      = var.subnets
  name                                          = each.value["name"]
  resource_group_name                           = each.value["resource_group_name"]
  virtual_network_name                          = each.value["virtual_network_name"]
  address_prefixes                              = each.value["address_prefixes"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "network_security_group" {
  for_each            = var.network_security_groups
  name                = each.value["name"]
  resource_group_name = each.value["resource_group_name"]
  location            = each.value["location"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "subnet_network_security_group_association" {
  for_each                  = var.subnet_network_security_group_associations
  network_security_group_id = lookup(var.nsg_id, each.value["network_security_group_variable_name"], null)
  subnet_id                 = lookup(var.subnet_id, each.value["subnet_variable_name"], null)
}

you can replace nsg_id with the resource ids of network security group and subnet_id with the output for resource ids of subnets
if you want terraform to retrieve output it would look like this :
output "id" {
  description = "The ID of the Subnet Network security group association"
  value = {
    for k, v in azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.subnet_network_security_group_association : k => v.id
  }
}


Using azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association resource won't work - as mentioned in the question, "We have a policy which denies the creation of subnets with no NSGs".
